# What will be the DD (Decision to Decision) path graph of the following code?

Tags: c++, graph, decision-tree, canonical-form

I need to draw the DD path graph of the following code:

```
    #include <iostream.h> 
    #include<conio.h> 
    main() 
    { 
      char name[16]; #1
      int age; #2
    
      cout << "Enter your name: "; #3
      cin >> name; #4
      cout << "Enter your age: "; #5
      cin >> age; #6
    
      if (age < 21) #7
       cout << "You young whippersnapper, " << name << "!\n"; #8
      else if (age < 40) #9
       cout << name << ", you're still in your prime!\n"; #10
      else if (age < 60) #11
       cout << "You're over the hill, " << name << "!\n"; #12
      else if (age < 80) #13
       cout << "I bow to your wisdom, " << name << "!\n"; #14
      else #15
       cout << "Are you really " << age << ", " << name << "?\n"; #16
    
      return 0; #17
    } #18
```

The DD path graph I obtained is given below:

[image]

I'm not sure that it is the correct graph. Can anyone please verify?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter for the confirmation. Actually this is the first time I am working on DD path graphs so I had doubts.